# How to utilize hibernate c3p0 connection pool?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm working on a standalone java application with hibernate and c3p0 connection pooling. I have a collection of data in the app and I want to save the new records to a remote MySQL database.
What I have done is simply iterate through the collection, query for the record in DB, and save it if it's not found. Each iteration, I obtain the session using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.
But this approach seems to be very slow. And the database process list shows that there's always only one connection active.

Here's my c3p0 config

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
```

So how can I improve it? Do I need extra configuration either for hibernate or mysql? Or is it possible to do it with multithread?

Comment: Do you have `<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the c3p0 connection pooling for hibernate. Take a look at this url [C3P0 configuration](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/)